# automate move to next slide of SlideShare using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, share, slide

My aim is to automate next Slide of SlideShare present on the web page using selenium.

How to next/previous SlideShare with Java code for Selenium?

```
WebElement slide = getDriver().findElement(By.id("slidesharePlayer")); // use the id of the searchbar to find it
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                slide.sendKeys("next()");
```

this fails to move next slide 
any idea how to move next slide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Actions(getDriver())
            .sendKeys(getDriver().findElement(By.id("slidesharePlayer")), Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
            .build().perform();
```

by press right key from key bord ...

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong.

1. Slideshare doesn't have any element with id `slidesharePlayer`.
2. Using `Thread.sleep` is not a good idea.
3. `sendKeys()` will send the keys `next()` to the element `slide`.

You can do something like..

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Next Slide')]").click();
```

which clicks on an `a` element with `title` property set to "Next Slide" .

Comment: not working got an error   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: The element could not be found

Comment: u will not rich to that url http://rrh-develop.elasticbeanstalk.com/learnerhome.htm#/basketState/112/basketItemStates/229379

Comment: @krishan- I dont' think webdriver support interacting with flash directly, though there are workarounds.

Comment: yes i got a little solution for that by pressing control+arrow key.. but i dont know how to do this with code